# MVVM Light Dynamic ViewModel Bestpractice

Tags: viewmodel, mvvm-light

In our application customers can design their ui on their on. For this we load the generated XAML at runtime.

We use MvvmLight as Mvvm Framework.

But I'm not sure what the best way is to get some kind of a dynamic view model.

So if the customer wants a new Datafield it should be aviable in the model.

My idea is to dynamically generated and compile a model assembly or to have converters which get their data from a Dictionary which is placed on the viewmodel.

Are there any better ideas, or some experiences and how to solve this best ?